# How to split a single feature in my polyline when it changes direction?

Tags: qgis

I'm wondering if there is a plugin in QGIS where i could split my lines in my poly line when it changes direction, as show in the picture below:

[image]

Comment: Have a look at the Explode Lines tool in the Processing Toolbox. It creates one feature per line segment, splitting at each vertex. Unless you have cases where straight line parts have several vertices? Also, do you have a tolerance angle to define your direction change?